# Best way to structure a CSS stylesheet

Tags: css, layout, structure, stylesheet

I am relatively new to CSS and yet I seem to have got the language reasonably well for a newbie. However, whilst many of the tutorials I have read often warn about "organising and structuring your stylesheet properly" (and I can certainly see why now I have created some rather long stylesheets myself) I cant for the life of me find any info about a standardised format for a styleheet or a logical pattern for layout that makes later human reading easy.

For example, do I create a comment-bracketed section for each "geographical" section of my page (header, row1, row2, article1 etc) and keep all styles for that section within those comment borders? The problem seems when I have styles that get re-used in other sections - and putting them under a section for page-wide styles then negates the purpose of grouping them by section at all. Likewise, structuring my stylesheet by grouping based on text styles, layout styles etc seems even more confusing.

Is there a "good practice"? I know this sounds dumb but it seems no matter what you do with HTML and CSS somebody is ready to tell you its wrong, bad practice or unsemantic and I'm left confused. I want my code to be a good example of my work in case an employer wants to check it in future.

Comment: [w3schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) recommends putting [one declaration per line](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never been actually taught, however I can let you know how I organise my CSS documents. As you say, I like to divide it up into "geographical" areas... i.e. the rules that apply to the header, the side bars, the main content, the footer, etc. And then, below these I add very specific rules, say if I need to style a form or a table on a particular page. Finally I add a "General Gubbins" section at the bottom when I add generic rules that may apply across the board.

Oh yes, I also like to add the designer's palette to the top for quick reference.

For example...

```
/*
PALETTE:
dark grey : #555555;
pink      : #d93575;
*/

/* HEADER */
#header {...}
#header ul {...}

/* SIDE BAR */
#side {...}
#side ul {....}

/* CONTENT */
#content{...}
#content p {....}

/* FOOTER */
#footer{...}
#footer div {....}

/* FORMS */
form {...}
input {...}

/* GENERAL GUBBINS */
.center {...}
strong {...}
floatleft {...}
```

Comment: In reading @spikes answer - that's a very good point. I use a few stylesheets too - one for "style", one for "layout/responsive", perhaps one for "generic" which I like to drop into all my sites (containing a clearfix and linear lists for example). If the site uses custom fonts that'd usually go in a separate stylesheet too.

Comment: I'd also like to add that you're absolutely right, @user2317093 - there will always be people telling you that what you are doing is wrong. It is up to you to decide whether it is or now based upon your own experiences. This is the way I like to do it - in other people eyes it may be 'right', it may be 'wrong' - but I believe that if anyone else picks up my work then it'd be pretty easy to figure out how I'd built it and, to me, that's the important thing. Source... school of hard knocks and impending deadlines! :-)

Comment: Thanks for this Doug, a great answer and I have stolen it :-) I especially like the designers palette idea, I've not seen that before but it makes full sense as I find myself making notes like this at the top of my stylesheet but now I have something posh to call it.

Comment: No problem at all... glad it helps. BTW, in case you're wondering, yes - I do actually label it "general gubbins" ! :)

Answer (score 1):

These guys advise you to "Organize the Stylesheet with a Top-down Structure" ( http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners/ ). I often use multiple style sheets. In MVC for instance - you can regiser styles on a per-view basis. That way you can put view-specific styles in a specific style sheet while not messing with your 'shared' or 'layout' one.